# How to know if a service is installed

Tags: python, service, subprocess, sshd

I'm looking for a way to check with a Python script if a service is installed. For example, if I want to check than a SSH server in installed/running/down in command line, I used :

```
service sshd status
```

If the service is not installed, I have a message like this:

```
sshd.service
  Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
  Active: inactive (dead)
```

So, I used a subprocess check_output to get this three line but the python script is not working. I used **shell=True** to get the output but it doen't work. Is it the right solution to find if a service is installed or an another method is existing and much more efficient?

There is my python script:

```
import subprocess
from shlex import split

output = subprocess.check_output(split("service sshd status"), shell=True)

if "Loaded: not-found" in output:
    print "SSH server not installed"
```

The probleme with this code is a subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command returned non-zero exit status 1. I know that's when a command line return something which doesn't exist but I need the result as I write the command in a shell

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if service exists with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328506/check-if-service-exists-with-ansible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just catch the error and avoid `shell=True`:

```
import subprocess

try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(["service", "sshd", "status"], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output)
    print(e.returncode)
```

Comment: The program told me that : Command '['service','shd','status']' returned non-zero exit status 3. It's not the same line as the shell command and I can't know if the service is installed or not

Comment: It works, I forgot to send stderr to stdout, the output will be in `e.output` on error

Answer (score 3):

Choose some different `systemctl` call, which differs for existing and non-existing services. For example

```
systemctl cat sshd
```

will return exit code `0` if the service exists and `1` if not. And it should be quite easy to check, isn't it?

Comment: I need to adapt my script but it's working even if the service is stopped. Thanks you!!